# $P(A^c \cap B^c)$

Tags: probability

I have $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(A \cup B)$, and $P(A \cap B)$. I'm asked to determine:

$P(A^c \cap B^c) = P(A^c) + P(B^c) - P(A^c \cup B^c)$.

The problem is that I do not know how to get $P(A^c \cup B^c)$, $A$ and $B$ are events in sample space $S$.

Comment: hint $A^\complement\cap B^\complement=(A\cup B)^\complement$

Comment: Hint: use a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following hints, see if you can put the pieces together:

1. $P(A^c \cap B^c) = P((A \cup B)^c)$
2. $P(A^c \cup B^c) = P((A\cap B)^c)$
3. $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$

And of course, $P(X^c) = 1-P(X)$

Comment: So $P(A^c \cap B^c) = P(A \cup B)^c = 1 - P(A \cup B)$?

Comment: @MohamedMagdy You want to write $P((A \cup B)^c)$ instead of $P(A \cup B)^c$. But otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 0):

A formal solution based on the DeMorgan law used twice:

$$
P(A^c \cap B^c) =
P\left(\left((A^c \cap B^c)^c\right)^c\right) =$$
$$=P\left(\left(A \cup B\right)^c\right)=$$$$=1-P\left(A \cup B\right)=$$
$$1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A\cap B)=1-P(A)+1-P(B)-1+P(A\cap B)=$$
$$=P(A^c)+P(B^c)-(1-P(A\cap B))=$$
$$=P(A^c)+P(B^c)-P((A\cap B)^c)=$$
$$=P(A^c)+P(B^c)-P(A^c\cup B^c).$$

Answer (score 0):

A *probability measure of the union of disjoint sets* equals the *sum of the probability measures for each set*.

Now, we can partition some of the relevant sets into unions of disjoint sets, $$\hspace{12ex}{\begin{align}A^\complement\cup B^\complement &= (A^\complement\cap B)\cup(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\cup(A\cap B^\complement)\\ A^\complement&=(A^\complement\cap B)\cup(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\\B^\complement&=(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\cup(A\cap B^\complement)\end{align}}$$

So $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A^\complement\cup B^\complement)&=\mathsf P((A^\complement\cap B)\cup(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\cup(A\cap B^\complement))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B)+\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)+\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement)\\[1ex] &\vdots\\[1ex]\mathsf P(A^\complement\cup B^\complement)+\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)&= \mathsf P(A^\complement)+\mathsf P(B^\complement)\\&\vdots\end{align}$$